# Perl Compilation error writing to .xlsx file

Tags: perl, excel-2007

```
 #!C:\Perl\bin
 #excel::writer attempt
 #allows IR-Serial-Parts tracking

 use strict;
 use warnings;
 use POSIX qw(strftime);
 use Excel::Writer::XLSX;
 use Spreadsheet::WriteExcel;


my $ref = strftime '%Y-%m-%d', localtime();     #create the datestamp
my $workbook;
my $worksheet;
my $i = 1;
my $ir = "IR Number: ";
my $sr = "UUT Serial: ";
my $pur = "How many parts used: ";
my $part = "Scan Part: ";
my @parts = "";


    if(-e 'tracking.xlsx'){
        my $workbook = Spreadsheet::WriteExcel->open('tracking.xlsx');  #open existing excel file

    }
    else{
        my $workbook = Excel::Writer::XLSX->new('tracking.xlsx');   #open new Excel if the date on comp has changed

    }
        $worksheet = $workbook->add_worksheet($ref);
        print $ir;  #ask user for IR #
        my $irs = <>;   #get user IR 
        print $sr;  #ask user for serial
        my $isr = <>;   #get serial from user
        print $pur; #get the number of parts used that way we can run the while loop below
        my $count = <>;

    While ($i < $count){

        print $part;
        my $scan = <>;
            push @parts, $scan;
            $i++;
        }




            $worksheet->write( 'A1', '$irs');
            $worksheet->write( 'A2', '$isr');
            $worksheet->write( 'A3', '@parts');
```

This script is in the first stages of dev. and I'm not a perl god in fact I'm brand-new but it's so awesome!!!
When I ran for the first time I had some errors simple enough to work out from the error messages but I can't seem to make sense of this and I feel it should have been easier to fix than my previous errors any help explaining why this is happening would be awesome!

```
 syntax error at writexcel.pl line 39, near "){"
 syntax error at writexcel.pl line 45, near "}"
 Execution of writexcel.pl aborted due to compilation errors.
 Press any key to continue . . .
```

Comment: `While` -> `while` (all lowercase; Perl is case sensitive)

Comment: I'm having to use notepad, I couldn't even tell thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

As @ThisSuitIsBlackNot pointed out the `while` in my while loop was capatilized and needed to be lower-case. Thanks for the quick reply!